# How to add Magento 2.1.2 extension via Web Setup Wizard?

Tags: php, magento-1.9, magento2

I am using Magento 2.1.2 version. Recently I move my magento site to AWS site will be working fine but when adding additional extension in my site I am getting these error.

Step 1: Readiness Check error

1. Check Cron Scripts
2. Check Component Dependency
3. PHP Version Check
4. PHP Settings Check *
5. PHP Extensions Check

[image]

My Magento site
PHP Version 5.6.29.
Please, anyone to help How can I install magento extension?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting indicates cron is not running. When cron doesn't run, we can't find the PHP version, etc.

Try [this troubleshooting topic](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/cron.html) and let us know if it helps.